# Why does TypeScript complain this "Object is possibly 'null'" when I have guarded against that?

Tags: typescript

I'm implementing a rudimentary Stack and cannot work out why TypeScript complains about the `peek()` method below.

```
type StackNode = { value: number };

export class Stack {
  topNode: StackNode | null;

  constructor() {
    this.topNode = null;
  }

  peek() {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      throw new Error('The stack is empty.');
    }

    return this.topNode.value; // Object is possibly 'null'. ts(2531)
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.topNode === null;
  }
}
```

How can `this.topNode` be `null` if I've checked it by calling `this.isEmpty()` first?

Comment: The compiler can't follow the method indirection: for instance you could overwrite that method at runtime with something else. If you inline the check it [works as expected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGBjA1gOQPYBNoF4oG8oA3eAGwFcIAuKAO3IFsAjCAJygF8BuAKB4gAeYdK2BREpeAGcpsBCgI8oUYOjAZsNOEjRZoAHzrlSpXkvHpaU4K3KJVrABQBKRcuXAAFgEspAOlV1PSg8ehNeZQ4+ZUgIZBc3d28AMyhHL18AtQ1cHFDjUld8c3cVT1Z0AHc6CGqAUVYKpwByABVPaGsdKF8oCAYwUD9m5wj3KJKoVghgclZaMszAnL8SCgguKAB6LagAeSYAKwh7HtlhGW8mUhAoZrDSZr8VKUcAJgBWAGYARmdzCbKXx1AagBLFUrTWbzRb+ZbBPL5cIAngcIA).

Comment: Also, I would *really* think carefully about having `peek` throw, that seems...unexpected. Java returns `null`, C# throws, so there's prior art both ways, just be careful.

Comment: Thanks, @JaredSmith. That answers my question.

Comment: The compiler does not perform control flow analysis across function boundaries (see [ms/TS#9998](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)) so `isEmpty()` has no effect on the apparent type of `this.topNode`. You could try to turn `isEmpty()` into a [type guard method](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) annotated with `this is {topNode: null}`, but it won't narrow `this` when `false`; you want an "else" type guard (see [ms/TS#15048](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048)) but those don't exist. The only option here is refactoring.